# Bash How input a command after a prompt password?

Tags: bash, input

I want automatically install zsh, when I run the command **chsh**. I have a prompt which ask password in input.

> Password :

After enter the password i have a second prompt, which ask me a shell path.

> Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
>
> Login Shell [/usr/bin/zsh]:

I want into a bash script :

1. run the command chsh
2. For the first prompt, let the user type his password
3. then enter /usr/bin/zsh in the second prompt

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `-s` option to specify the shell instead of prompting.

```
chsh -s /usr/bin/zsh
```